# WordPress plugin isn't deployed to OpenShift

Tags: wordpress, openshift

After setting up WordPress site  on OpenShift, I tried to upload new plugin from my local repo, according [this](https://developers.openshift.com/languages/php/wordpress.html) manual, but nothing was uploaded to OpenShift.

Step I've done:

```
# cloning WordPress app from OpenShift
rhc git-clone  -a wpdev

# Going to plugins folder on local machine
cd ~/openshift/wpdev/.openshift/plugins

# cloning my plugin from GitHub to openshift plugins folder
git clone https://github.com/samuelsh/youtube-channel-player.git

# standart add/commit/push
git add plugins
git commit -m "youtube-channel-player deploy to openshift"
git push
```

After checking my `wpdev` app on openshift, looks like my plugin isn't uploaded.
What could go wrong here?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, appeared it was git submodule issues.

Trying explicitly add new files to repo resulted following error:

```
git add .openshift/plugins/youtube-channel-player/*
fatal: Pathspec '.openshift/plugins/youtube-channel-player/admin' is in submodule '.openshift/plugins/youtube-channel-player'
```

Removing the directory from git and adding it again worked for me:

```
 git rm --cached directory
 git add directory
```